# How can I discover what configurations.default.collect means in Gradle?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to build a jar out of a kotlin/gradle project. Recently I stumbled upon this exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics`

Happily, I've found this [repo](https://github.com/niksw7/gradle-kotlin-demo/blob/master/build.gradle#L19) that already solves that. However, I cannot find specific documentation about this block:

```
configurations.default.collect {
    it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
```

I mean, I want to understand to be able to come up with possible solutions by myself in the future when I'll have other gradle problems. But this kinda looks it came out of nowhere. For example, [here](https://medium.com/@adrianmarkperea/understanding-gradle-by-creating-an-executable-kotlin-jar-8f554c7090c5), we have `configurations.compile.collect`. What could be the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a solid understanding of Gradle and some understanding of Groovy to understand what is going on.

```
jar {
    from {
        configurations.default.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

- The `jar` is referring to the [`Jar` Gradle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html). So the author is configuring the `jar` task.
- The author is invoking the [`from(java.lang.Object[])`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar.html#org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar:from(java.lang.Object[])) and providing a list of directories or a ZIP file.
- `configurations` refers to the [`ConfigurationContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer.html), it is Gradle's primary way of placing dependencies into "buckets".
- `configurations.default` is saying "Give me the configuration having name 'default'." There are a plethora of other *container* methods Gradle provides. See the Javadoc [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html).
- The `.collect { }` is a Groovy method. You can read about it [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure))
- Finally `zipTree()` is a method provided by Gradle. You can read its Javadoc [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:zipTree(java.lang.Object))